# AWS Micro instance: upgrade to Medium?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm running an AWS Micro instance and I would like to upgrade it to a Medium instance.

One way I could do this is just to bite the bullet and admit that I'll lose some of the traffic: stop Micro, create image, create Medium from that image. Should take 5 minutes, that's acceptable (for me, given circumstances).

However the problem here is the domain name. The Medium instance will likely have a different IP and then I have to point the domain name to the new IP, and that might take hours. That's not acceptable.

Suggestions?

Comment: did you look into setting an [elastic IP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) ?

Comment: Pointing the domain name to a new IP will *not* take hours, if you set a sensible TTL on your DNS A-record *now* (like 60 seconds) and then wait for the previous TTL to expire before changing anything.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, it should be possible to spin up the new instance, install the application and connect it to the same database as the old instance. That way you change the IP address in your DNS settings and users can seamlessly start using the new instance as DNS records propagates.

If your application is designed in such a way that this is not feaseable, you should look into setting up a proxy / load balancer that just forwards requests to the preferred server. You then set up your DNS to point to the load balancer / proxy, and then you can spin up your new instance and put it into operation by just updating the IP address setting in the load balancer and then all traffic will go to the new server instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Your micro instance needs to have an elastic IP address assigned to it.  You can add one now and then change your DNS to use the new elastic iP.  This is an IP address that you can hold onto and connect it to any of your instances.  The advantage is that you can spin up your new Medium instance.  Then just detach your elastic IP from your micro and attach it to your medium instance.  Downtime should be 30 seconds or less.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html#concepts-elastic-addressing

Comment: Except that if the instance does not already have an elastic IP, attaching one will release the current public IP address, which introduces exactly the same problem OP is trying to avoid.